# How do I deny some keywords on user input

Tags: php, arrays, validation

Example user input that should be denied:

- House for **`sale`**
- Car for **`rent`**
- **`WTB`** iphone with cheap price

How do I make my code deny inputs like those above?

```
$title = array('rent','buy','sale','sell','wanted','wtb','wts');
$user_title = stripslashes($_POST['title']);
if (in_array($user_title, $title)) {
    $error = '<p class="error">Do not include ' . $user_title . ' on your title</p>';
}
```

Comment: I hope that this is only being used as an exercise, because spam prevention is certainly more complex than searching for substrings. You may want to use a plug-in such as Akismet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your denied words to be complete words and not just part of another word for it to be considered denied, you can use a regex based solution with word boundaries:

```
// array of denied words.
$deniedWords = array('rent','buy','sale','sell','wanted','wtb','wts');

// run preg_quote on each array element..as it may have a regex meta-char in it.
$deniedWords = array_map('preg_quote',$deniedWords);

// construct the pattern as /(\bbuy\b|\bsell\b...)/i
$pat = '/(\b'.implode('\b|\b',$deniedWords).'\b)/i';

// use preg-match_all to find all matches
if(preg_match_all($pat,$user_title,$matches)) {

    // $matches[1] has all the found word(s), join them with comma and print.
    $error = 'Do not include ' . implode(',',$matches[1]);    
}
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/DdvRr)

Comment: +1, this is the solution I wanted to do but didn't have the time. Very elegant and scales well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
$title = array('rent','buy','sale','sell','wanted','wtb','wts');
$user_title = stripslashes($_POST['title']);

foreach($title as $word)
{
    if (stripos($user_title, $word) !== false)
    {
        $error = '<p class="error">Do not include ' . $word . ' on your title</p>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use `stripos()` though, otherwise it'll miss `RENT`

Comment: +1 for not using regex, not that it's a bad thing, it's just a little slow :-)

Comment: A regexp would actually be much faster as the number of keywords increase.

Comment: Unfortunately using this will also prevent you from using words that contain any of those words as substrings, for example "Brentwood" or "Trenton". And even then, this is pretending that the whole idea of a substring blacklist is actually an even remotely viable way of preventing users from selling on your site...

Comment: @Josh @Lotus: I got it, codeaddict's solution is not only works better, but it is faster as well (I have profiled it, mine (modified to collect all word) is ~400µs, codeaddict's is ~280µs).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex:

```
if (preg_match("/(rent|buy|sale|sell|wanted|wtb|wts)/is", $user_title)) {
    $error = '<p class="error">Do not include ' . $user_title . ' on your title</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize explode() in order to separate the words in $user_title and check each one to ensure it does not exist in $title.

```
$invalidWords = '';

$words = explode(' ', stripslashes($_POST['title']));
foreach($words as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $title)) {
        $invalidWords .= ' ' . $word;
    }
}

if (!empty($invalidWords)) {
    echo '<p class="error">Do not include the following words in your title: ' . $invalidWords . '</p>';
}
```

RegEx is probably best, but off-hand I cannot easily figure out the expression required in order for you to be able to output all of the invalid words in a list to the user.